# Dblclick event handler not responding for apple devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently my application uses a FancyTree jquery plugin, the dblclick event is not working only for apple devices, when running in google chrome developer mode set on iphone7/8 it gives me the following error in console:
[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.

However when switch off device toolbar, it is working fine.
same as for android and windows devices.

Also installing chrome on apple device will not work.

What can be the problem?

Thank you.

Installing doubletap.js gives no result.
Code from event handler in plugin

```
.on("click" + ns + " dblclick" + ns, function(event) {
                        if (opts.disabled) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        var ctx,
                            et = FT.getEventTarget(event),
                            node = et.node,
                            tree = self.tree,
                            prevPhase = tree.phase;

                        // self.tree.debug("event(" + event.type + "): node: ", node);
                        if (!node) {
                            return true; // Allow bubbling of other events
                        }
                        ctx = tree._makeHookContext(node, event);
                        // self.tree.debug("event(" + event.type + "): node: ", node);
                        try {
                            tree.phase = "userEvent";
                            switch (event.type) {
                                case "click":
                                    ctx.targetType = et.type;
                                    if (node.isPagingNode()) {
                                        return (
                                            tree._triggerNodeEvent(
                                                "clickPaging",
                                                ctx,
                                                event
                                            ) === true
                                        );
                                    }
                                    return tree._triggerNodeEvent(
                                        "click",
                                        ctx,
                                        event
                                    ) === false
                                        ? false
                                        : tree._callHook("nodeClick", ctx);
                                case "dblclick":
                                    ctx.targetType = et.type;
                                    return tree._triggerNodeEvent(
                                        "dblclick",
                                        ctx,
                                        event
                                    ) === false
                                        ? false
                                        : tree._callHook("nodeDblclick", ctx);
                            }
                        } finally {
                            tree.phase = prevPhase;
                        }
                    });
```

[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Comment: can you update the question and add your event listener code.

Comment: Dear Doc-Han, added all code for this function.

Comment: Dear Doc-Han, again I changed code, now you can view the event handler from the fancytree plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an obscure issue in Chrome. It is caused by a change back in Chrome 56 which is intended to improve scroll performance on mobile.

The workaround is to add a CSS rule like this:

```
#modal_valve
{
  touch-action: none;
}
```

You may need to add it to other elements as well, depending on which elements gets dragged.

Comment: Dear ocBiermann, it is not because of the modal, because the event doesn't get fired at all, if I please a debug line inside the event handler, this also doesnt get logged.